# User registration linked to firebase authentication but not real time database

Tags: flutter

I have recently started to code and I am falling in love with it. Right now I am trying to set up a registration form that automatically saves the information in the real time database. However, the account information only gets stored in Firebases' authentication section... I've watched a few tutorials and searched for the past 6 hours for a solution but I could not come up with any reason as to why this is not working. Could anyone take a look at my code and help me out? <3

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

 void registerNewUser(BuildContext context) async
  {
    final User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailTextEditingController.text,
          password: passwordTextEditingController.text)
        .catchError((errMsg){
      displayToastMessage("Fehler: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
    }))
        .user;

    if(firebaseUser != null) {
      Map userDataMap = {
        "name": nameTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "phone": phoneTextEditingController.text.trim(),
      };
      usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);

      displayToastMessage("Your account has been created! :)", context);

      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
    }
    else {
      displayToastMessage("User could not be created.", context);
    }
  }
}
```

And in my main dart file...

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
```

Comment: any ideas...? :(